# Button doesn't get clicked using capybara (using Firefox and xvfb)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I'm trying to set up cucumber tests in docker so I found out that I need to use xvfb in order to at least run tests without GUI. After hours of struggling I've finally run tests, but now:

I'm testing sending data through the form. I'm filling necessary fields and I'm clicking the button, but it doesn't do anything. It works fine when I'm browsing through the page; it is okay when I run cucumber locally without docker (with or without headless Firefox), but it fails in that one case. When I'm debugging it sees the button, `click` returning `'ok'`, but it does nothing. Also, current_url doesn't change, and Product is not saved to DB (so I assume button does not get clicked).

Could it be a problem with not compiled scripts files, maybe JavaScript doesn't work properly in headless Firefox or something else?

I've updated capybara to latest version. Code for testing:

```
step 'I click on Products link'
expect(page).to have_content "You don't have any products yet!"
click_link('ADD YOUR FIRST PRODUCT')
expect(page).to have_content 'Add new product'
fill_in('Product Name', with: 'Product')
fill_in('Price', with: 19.99)
fill_in('Description', with: 'This is test product')
find(:xpath, "//input[@type='submit'][@value='SAVE PRODUCT']").click
expect(page).to have_content 'Your product is LIVE' # it fails HERE
click_link('BACK TO PRODUCTS')
expect(page).to have_content 'Product'
click_link('Edit')
expect(page).to have_content 'This is test product'
find_all(:xpath, "//a[@href='#productVariants']").first.click
expect(page).to have_content 'CREATE VARIANTS'
find_all(:xpath, "//a[@href='#customizeWidget']").first.click
expect(page).to have_content 'Button background'
find_all(:xpath, "//a[@href='#flashSales']").first.click
expect(page).to have_content 'Enable Sales Boosters'
```

And the error message is:
`expected to find text "Your product is LIVE" (...) (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)` (should I post page content also?)
It works that way - after save the same page for editing product is shown but modal is revealed and there should have this text. I've saved a screenshot, a page was not reloaded and the modal was not shown (modal is shown if a product is saved properly).

Comment: There can be different possibilities, there could be a error on the page javascript and that may be causing the issue

Comment: The Capybara `click` method returns the element that was clicked in current versions of Capybara, so if it's returning 'ok' you're not calling the Capybara click, or your version of Capybara is out of date -  update capybara and show an example of your test code

Comment: I've added code to question (edit: now I have javascripts loaded in test env)

Comment: @sbulat Please also include the part of the test that fails, and the exact error message of the failure  - Also note that rather than finding by xpath `find(:xpath, "//input[@type='submit'][@value='SAVE PRODUCT']").click` you can just do `click_button('SAVE PRODUCT')` - would read much better

Comment: I've added more code. Should I add page content also?

Comment: @sbulat Assuming the modal you describe is from some JS library and not a system modal (`window.alert`) your test code looks fine -- does your rails `test.log` show the form submission occurring?

Comment: @sbulat as a side note - why are you using all xpaths -- they make reading tests way more difficult than they need to be  `find_all(:xpath, "//a[@href='#productVariants']").first.click`  => `find_all(:link, href: ''#productVariants").first.click`  if you actually need the `first` in there due to multiple matching links, if not it's just `click_link(href: '#productVariants')`

Comment: @ThomasWalpole It does not. The last entry is for rendering new product page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154997/discussion-between-thomas-walpole-and-sbulat).

Answer (score 0):

Try precompiling your assets/javascripts in test environment. Problem might be with your javascript not running.

Comment: I've precompiled assets again, but it seems that javascript files are not loaded on the page at all. It is blocked in some way that my main js file doesn't load rest of needed files?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was I had wrong version of Firefox installed in my container and I guess my version of selenium (2.53.0) was not working properly with FF 52.

Comment: Selenium v2 only works up to FF 47.  After that you need to use the gecko driver.